# Exchange Apple Watch after 14 day policy

Tags: apple-watch, apple-inc

I bought my watch 19 days ago so it's 5 days over the policy. But it froze after the return policy date and I was wondering if they will let me exchange it for a new one. Anyone have answers or experience exchanging a new Apple product after the 14 day period. My watch had a problem after and it's not a lot after the 14 day window so I was wondering if they will still exchange it for me.

Comment: Did it freeze once, and worked since after rebooting or waiting? - Or is it just completely frozen and won't operate anymore? If it is the former, don't expect a free replacement. If it is the latter, then certainly do expect a free replacement. My Apple Watch failed after almost a year where it froze and won't function, and I got a free replacement right away.

Answer (score 2):

If by it froze you mean it's not working anymore, then it's a case for warranty.  That is one year long.  [Here is](https://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/warranty-us.html) a legal description for the US, but it is similar in other countries.